# Safely exit Qt thread on exit application

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am trying to create a thread for a Scanner class which handles all the events for this particular class, thereby freeing the GUI thread. I have an exit button on my GUI which simply calls qApp->quit() to exit the application, but I am not sure how to deal with the thread in my Scanner class. I am seeing the following errors in the debug log when the application is exited.

```
QThread::wait: Thread tried to wait on itself
QThread::wait: Thread tried to wait on itself
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

In Scanner.cpp (Omitted other functions)

```
Scanner::Scanner() :
{
    this->moveToThread(&m_thread);

    connect(&m_thread, &QThread::finished, this, &QObject::deleteLater);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(StartEnroll()), this, SLOT(StartEnrollment()));

    m_thread.start();
}

Scanner::~Scanner()
{
    m_thread.quit(); // Not sure if this is the correct
    m_thread.wait();
}
```

In main Window.cpp (Omitted other functions)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); 
    connect(ui->ExitButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(Quit()));
    connect(&m_scanner, SIGNAL(FinishedEnroll(bool)), this, SLOT(EnrollDone(bool)));
}

void MainWindow::Quit()
{
    close();
    qApp->quit();
}
```

Any pointers on how to quit safely quit the application in a multi-threaded application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to let the `Scanner` class know that the application is exiting.

Add the following line to the constructor of `MainWindow`

```
connect(qApp, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &m_scanner, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

UPDATE:

```
connect(&m_thread, &QThread::finished, this, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

Should not be in the constructor of `Scanner`

and

```
m_thread.quit(); 
m_thread.wait();
```

should not be in the destructor of `Scanner`

In fact, `m_thread` should not be part of `Scanner` in any way. The `QThread` class does not represent a thread, it is a thread manager and should be owned and controlled from the thread where it was created.

There are a number of methods of using threads in Qt, many not documented very well. If you want to use the

```
workerObject->moveToThread(&thread);
thread.start();
```

way of using threads, then `m_thread` should be a member of `MainWindow` class and these function calls should be made in it's constructor.

Comment: That didn't work. I still got : QThread::wait: Thread tried to wait on itself
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running

Comment: The Scanner class should not be trying to quit the thread or wait on it. The worker thread should be owned and controlled by the GUI thread.

Comment: Thanks, posted my corrected solution based on your response.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for clarifying and for the solutions posted above. Here is what I did based on what was posted before.

ScannerThread.h

```
#include <QThread>

class ScannerThread : public QThread
{

public:
    ScannerThread();
    ~ScannerThread();
};
```

ScannerThread.cpp

```
#include "scannerthread.h"

ScannerThread::ScannerThread()
{
    connect(this, &QThread::finished, this, &QObject::deleteLater);
}

ScannerThread::~ScannerThread()
{
    quit();
    wait();

}
```

In MainWindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
   void Quit();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Scanner m_scanner;
    ScannerThread m_scannerThread;
};
```

In MainWindow.cpp (Omitting other functions)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    m_scanner.moveToThread(&m_scannerThread);
    m_scannerThread.start();

    connect(ui->ExitButton, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(Quit()));
    connect(qApp, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), &m_scanner, SLOT(deleteLater()));

}

void MainWindow::Quit()
{
    close();
    qApp->quit();
}
```

This seemed to work fine for me. If you see any errors please correct, and thanks for helping with this.

Answer (score 0):

First you should move your `QThread` out of the Scanner class. A `QThread` manages a thread, so you can't call functions that are related to the thread management inside that thread itself. That's the reason you're getting the message about the thread waiting on itself.

You should rather have something like that:

```
m_scanner.moveToThread(&m_thread);//make the thread a member of your window
m_thread.start();
```

Then, in your `quit` function, do as you want, either waiting on the thread (better) or terminating it (worse) before exiting, or a tradeoff, such as:

```
void MainWindow::Quit()
{
    close();
    //Wait maximum 1 second
    if(!m_thread.wait(1000) {
        m_thread.terminate();
    }
    qApp->quit();
}
```

Comment: QObjects cannot have children in different threads. If you create Scanner as a child of MainWindow, then move Scanner to a different thread, it will lose it's parentage.